# Radio button does not work when I apply css to it

Tags: css, html

CSS:

```
input[type='radio'] {

    position: absolute;
    left: 42.5em;
    top: 29.5em;    

}

input[type='radio'][value='no'] {

    position: absolute;
    left: 46.4em;
    top: 29.5em;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="relocate" value="yes" />Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="relocate" value="no" />No
```

When I apply the styles to the radio buttons it does not work, it does not toggle, it gets stuck. CSS HTML

Comment: Can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this? I suspect a `z-index` issue.

Comment: [Toggles just fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Y355L/)

Comment: Try to remove `position:absolute;`, it should work.

Comment: @PeeHaa not for me, Chrome 23 :(

Comment: You can't just click on the text, you need to click on the button part.

Comment: @ConnorRoberts How sure are you about that, because both Canary and stable work for me?

Comment: bborisovs, thanks it worked, but why does position:absolute cause a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `position:absolute;`, because an element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. Since you do not have any parent positioning in this example the `input` gets positioned relatively to the `html` block.